# react-native with react-navigation and redux [transfer state across screen]

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am new to react-native and all its libraries.

I am trying to get my InputText's content across to the next screen using react-redux, but I am not sure how to do it properly. The documentations are too verbose but just explain the theories with nothing practical.

I have 2 screens in my StackNavigator as follows:

```
const StackNav = StackNavigator({
  SignName: { screen: SignNameScreen},
  SignBday: { screen: SignBdayScreen}
})
```

each of the `SignNameScreen` and `SignBdayScreen` just has TextInput and I just want to get the user input across the screen.

```
class SignNameScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  handleNext() {
    Alert.alert("handle button next pressed")
//     navigate("SignBday")
  }
  handleOnPress() {
    Alert.alert("handle button login pressed")
  }
  submitFunc = () => {
    const payload = {
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password
    }
    console.log(payload)
    Alert.alert("hello: " + payload.email)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 
'space-around'}}>
        <TextInput placeholder="first name"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.firstname = text}/>
        <TextInput placeholder="last name"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.lastname = text}/>
      <Button 
        title="Next"
//         onPress={this.handleNext} // this doesnt work, the function cannot access props
        onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate("SignBday")}}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried various methods like creating `reducer`, export the class using `connect` etc, but everything just breaks the code. Would anyone point me in the right direction, please?

I have tried numerous sample project from github but they are either unbuildable or unrunnable because of various node problems.. sorry, javascript is my weak point too.

Thanks a lot for your help.

[image: The screenshot]

Comment: You can pass it as a param while navigating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate like this

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignBday', { 'Param_Name': 'Param_Value' })}
```

Then get the param in another screen like this

```
const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
```

To get the value of parameter in next screen use

```
params.Param_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the app, if it is a simple app with less states, then you probably don't need to use Redux.

Without redux.
You would need to pass it like this.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('NewPage',{ paramKey: paramValue })
```

And retrieve it on the other other page like

```
const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
```

Also make sure that you are having navigation access at that given component.

With Redux is a little more complicated.

You would need a some setup and an action and reducer, something like what is done [here](https://github.com/mbeaudru/react-native-sample) and [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/tree/master/examples/ReduxExample).

Goodluck!